# 3706: Syntax error: expected something between '=' and the 'BETWEEN' keyword TERADATA Database

Tags: sql, teradata, microstrategy, teradatasql

I've been trying to create an ApplySimple and i keep getting this error but i dont know what is wrong with it.

```
ApplySimple("CASE 
    WHEN #0=  BETWEEN '0' AND ' 5' THEN  '0 a 5' 
    WHEN #0=  BETWEEN '6' AND '10' THEN '6 a 10'
    ELSE  'Más de 10'
    END"; [RESOLUTION_DAYS_QTY])
```

Comment: Remove the `=`? Additionally this is probably a numeric columns, thus `BETWEEN 0 AND 5 THEN`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you actually trying to test if 0 is between 6 and 10? Or is #0 supposed to be an argument?

Comment: The #0= is used in MicroStrategy to indicate the table [RESOLUTION_DAYS_QTY]

Comment: The `#0` indicates where the value of the first (counting from zero) fact, attribute, or metric will be substituted in the generated SQL. The `=` does not belong here.

Comment: CASE WHEN column_name between '0' and '5' - is the format you are looking for.